# How can I decode in PHP a json string that has a json string as a value inside?

Tags: php, json

I need to decode a JSON string in PHP but the thing is that the string has a JSON encoded string as one of the value. Something like that :

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "{\"key3\":\"{\\\"key4\\\":\\\"value4\\\"}\"}"
}
```

I'm trying to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it into an array but it always fail with the error that the syntax is incorrect. If I put it in any validator you can find online, it says the string is valid. Should I use another method to parse the string?

PS: I am fine with the fact that once decoded, the value of key2 won't be an array but instead a string that I would have to decode again.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try this : 
$decoded = json_decode('your string');

Comment: How did you get this JSON value “into” your script? If you wrote this as string in _code_, then you need to pay attention to the backslashes … Start by making a debug output of the variable you are passing to json_encode, and see if you still got as many backslashes as you thought you did …

Comment: this is a hornet's nest. Post the code where this (valid but unwieldy) json is produced, you might have more help available here.

Comment: I got this from a server to server call from an external endpoint I don't control unfortunately. The other end gives me a big json which at some point contains some sort of receipt that it is json encoded and put into a string. The rest of the JSON is a usual JSON structure but one of the value is the json encoded receipt put as a string value. I have to decode everything before processing it properly.

Comment: What you have posted is not valid JSON. It *would* be valid JSON if all the PHP was removed and the content between `'` and `'` was left as it is. That way the ```\``` characters would be treated as JSON escape characters and not PHP escape characters. Likely you introduced a new problem in constructing your reduced test case.

Comment: @Quentin I was overzealous in my edit. Rolled back now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided input - you must replace all those nasty backslashes and double quotes in order to get proper JSON:

```
<?php
$s = '{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "{\"key3\":\"{\\\"key4\\\":\\\"value4\\\"}\"}"
}';

$s = str_replace('\\', '', $s);
$s = str_replace('"{', '{', $s);
$s = str_replace('}"', '}', $s);

print_r(json_decode($s, true));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[key1] => value1
[key2] => Array
    (
        [key3] => Array
            (
                [key4] => value4
            )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is bad, you have unnecessary " around {}

http://prntscr.com/mjkrcb

```
$a = '{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {"key3":{"key4":"value4"}}
}';

var_dump(json_decode($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your string with this line of code:

```
    $json_string.= '{"id":"'.$variable.'","name":"'.preg_replace("~[\"]~","\\\\\"",$variable_name).'","other_name":"'.preg_replace("~[\"]~","",$other_name_variable).'"},';
```

You have to convert string to JSON array then.
Don't forget about **right quotes** and string format.
More about JSON: https://www.json.org/ -here you can find explanations and examples
More for preg_replace function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score -1):

you can use json_decode() twice or more

```
$a = {
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "{\"key3\":\"{\\\"key4\\\":\\\"value4\\\"}\"}"
 }
 $b = json_decode($a);
 $c = json_decode($b->key2);
```

It's give you a object with key3. and again you can use json_decode().

It's the correct string for your structure if It's diffrence from it , it may be wrong .

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"{\"key3\":\"{\\\"key4\\\":\\\"value4\\\"}\"}"}
```

NOTE : I think I should write a edit on this . when you use \ in string it put \ in your string if you want copy exactly this you should replace them . if you use json_last_error() you give syntax error in this string .

NOTE : If you do like the above answer from @mitkosoft , you change your structure because of two problem . First , you change your object to to array . Second , if you decode in first level you should get your "key2" value a string not an array . It's a json string that you can do it decode again .

Comment: `$a = { ... }` is not even JSON to begin with.

Comment: That's where my problem is. I tried json_decode but it returns a json error saying that the synthax is invalid. I can't do json_decode($a) in your example

Comment: {"key1":"value1","key2":"{\"key3\":\"{\\\"key4\\\":\\\"value4\\\"}\"}"}
it's right json that created by json_encode in php .

Comment: that's going nowhere : $b is `null` and the next line will fail.

Comment: Yes you don't copy this exactly because in php when you use \\ it put \ in string and if use json_last_eroor() you get wrong syntax . 
so you should replace them if you want copy this